# Store canvas screenshot to local filesystem with Filesystem API

Tags: javascript, download, native-file-system-api-js

I am developing a small web-application with a threejs Renderer where I want to be able to store some screenshots to my local filesystem at a specific location. Rendering the images and creating the snapshots works, only the storage/download part gives me headache.

I create the snapshot this way:

```
    let imageData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL('image/png');
    console.log(imageData); // data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABFAAAANBC...
```

Now to download this, there are several methods: `window.location.href = imageData;`does trigger a download (and several alert messages from the browser). But the downloaded image is stored as a file called *download* inside the Download-Folder. If added the File-Extension *.png* it can be opened. This is not a useful solution, several downloads in a row will hardly be assigned.

So another working method is to build a download-link and trigger its click-method:

```
    let a_element = document.createElement('a');
    a_element.setAttribute('href', imageData.replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
    a_element.setAttribute('download', 'screenshot.png');
    a_element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(a_element);
    a_element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a_element);
```

This does download the screenshot with a custom-name to the Download folder, it's almost what I want, but i'd like to have them stored in a custom folder as well. That's where the Filesystem-API comes in. The drawback is, that every download has to be confirmed, but not having to move the files manually from the download folder would pay off for that.

```
    const options = {
        types: [
            {
            description: 'Images',
            accept: {
                'image/png': ['.png'],
            },
            },
        ],
        suggestedName: 'Screenshot.png',
        };
    imgFileHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker(options);
    console.log("Save File chosen");
    const writable = await imgFileHandle.createWritable();
    await writable.write(imageData);
    await writable.close();
```

This seems to work, but the file that is stored is not a valid image. It contains only Text (same as the output of the console). How should I treat the imageData to download it as an image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the File System Access API, you're almost there, but instead of a data URL, you need to provide the data as a blob. To create a blob from a data URL, you can use the code below:

```js
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  const byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  const mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
  const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  const ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  const blob = new Blob([ab], {type: mimeString});
  return blob;
}
```

It may be easier to get the `Blob` directly, via the [`toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method. This should work in Three.js as well, since `renderer.domElement` is a `CanvasElement`.